# Python 3.12.2 Tool Script file 'loader-o.py' does not exist

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tariq\Downloads\Blank-main\Blank\env\Scripts\process.py", line 9, in <module>
    

import pyaes
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaes'
```

288 INFO: PyInstaller: 6.5.0, contrib hooks: 2024.3
288 INFO: Python: 3.12.2
307 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0
Script file 'loader-o.py' does not exist.

Can anyone help me, i dont know anythink about python

I installed pyaes already but nothing changes

Comment: Show us the exact command you used to install pyaes, and show us exactly how you run this code.

Comment: pip install pyaes

Its an grabber i will troll my friend here is the github install https://github.com/Blank-c/Blank-Grabber/issues

Comment: Show us exactly how you run the code.  Are you running it from the command line, or using an IDE, or some other way?

Comment: Can you help me maybe?  @John Gordon

Comment: Its an windows bat @JohnGordon

Comment: @JohnGordon It works for my friends